# How to show a message if the browser is not part of the browserlist?

Tags: reactjs, safari

I'm using a browserlist configuration that supports browser with a marketshare > 0.2%. If somebody uses an old safari browser, the user will only see a blank page. How can I show a message to the user, that this browser is outdated?

browserlist

```
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    ...
  }
```

Supported safari versions:

```
safari 15.2-15.3
safari 15.1
safari 14.1
safari 14
safari 13.1
samsung 16.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you fix it with a noscript tag?
It will appear when javascript is blocked or when a browser doesn't support scripting. If this is enough, you can do something like this

```html
<noscript>Your browser is outdated!</noscript>
```

see: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp

Otherwise I would use Modernizr (https://modernizr.com/)
to check for the features you need, and show a message when they're not present. Hope this helps.

Comment: but these browser support js, but they do not support es6

Comment: Then I recommend Modernizr